# What is recommended - UC or EV or EV UC certificate?

Tags: security-certificate, ucc-certificate

We are implementing Exchange 2010 server and an eCommerce site. Both of these need certificates and I am confused what to use? I know Exchange need UC certificate. Can I use it for the ecommerce site as well? I did read EV is recommended for web sites..

I would like to know what to use and the recommended procedures. Here how we will be using the certificates:

1. We are planning to use *.net for testing Exchange server
2. Will be using *.com for Exchange server (Production)
3. Will be using *.com for ecommerce site (Production)

I also heard about certificates which are both EV UC.. please recommend the correct certificates to use.

Answer (score 0):

The EV certificate (Extended Validation) supports presenting more information to the user. Typically an green bar or field is used to signal that the site is secured using SSL when an EV certificate is in use.

An EV is no more secure than a regular certificate, however users might find it easier to trust a site due to the way the certificate is presented in web browsers. 
[image: EV certificate]

The UC certificate (Unified Communications Certificate) let's one use multiple domains inside one certificate. A UC certificate can also be used for websites, however any secondary domain listed in the certificate will also be listed, so if you do not want sites to appear "connected" to each other, you should not use this type of certificate.